# Вылетает активити либо кидает на другое активити джава

Tags: java, android-studio, activity, исключения

Почему то вылетает активити и приложение показывает FATAL EXCEPTION
Логи прикрепляю:

```
 01-07 12:25:23.128 20908-20908/com.go.fenom.home E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: com.go.fenom.home, PID: 20908
                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.go.fenom.home/com.go.fenom.home.Import}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: ScrollView can host only one direct child
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2793)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2864)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1567)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
                                                                    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: ScrollView can host only one direct child
                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child
                                                                       at android.widget.ScrollView.addView(ScrollView.java:281)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:873)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:832)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:872)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:832)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                                       at com.go.fenom.home.Import.onCreate(Import.java:29)
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6910)
                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2746)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2864)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1567)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
```

Добавляю код файла

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="140sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
            android:background="@drawable/background_home">
        </ImageView>

    </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_work"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Робота"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:theme="@style/CustomAnimationButton" />
    </ScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
    <!-- copy from activity_home and paste it here.-->
```

Comment: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.go.fenom.home/com.go.fenom.home.Import}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: ScrollView can host only one direct child       это нам говорит о необходимости посмотреть на этот xml

Comment: Эти проблемы как я знаю надо исправить в Манифесте

Comment: А что тут не так? Добавил код файла.

Comment: ScrollView can host only one direct child это сообщение намекает что у вас ошибка в разметке, покажите эту часть файла или весь файл что лучше

Comment: А вот и ваша ошибка, у вас в ScrollView находится два дочерних элемента, хотя более одного нельзя, оберните ваш LinearLayout и Button во что то, например в LinearLayout или в Relative или во что вам удобно

Comment: Файл добавил в вопрос.

Comment: И правильнее обернуть в такой контейнер который принимает размер по содержимому (LinearLayout ), тогда Scroll будет правильно работать

Comment: И в следующий раз, чтоб сэкономить время почитайте stacktrace, java довольно дружелюбно пишет где ошибка и какая она (в 90 % случаев), в отличии от c++ например

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Но на следующей активности есть кнопка которая ведет на третью активность но меня бросает на главный екран..

Comment: это уже совсем другая история ) там надо смотреть что у вас по нажатию происходит, к этому вопросу не относится как я понимаю. Внимательно пересмотрите обработчик нажатия и, кажется мне, найдете в чем причина.

Comment: Если у вас появилась другая проблема, которую вы не можете решить самостоятельно, создайте новый вопрос. Не надо в комментариях обсуждать проблему, не связанную с текущим вопросом